# Custom commands in radiopanel don't work right?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I tried to implement control of features in my config in radiopanel, but the commands don't  work right. I have this in radiopanel.txt:

```
"bhop"
{
    "hotkey"    "1"
    "label" "Bhop Mod On/Off"
    "cmd"   "bhop"
}
```

And in my autoexec:

```
alias bhop "bhopon" 
alias bhopon "bind MWHEELDOWN +jump;bind MWHEELUP +jump;alias bhop bhopoff; playvol buttons\blip1 0.25"
alias bhopoff "bind MWHEELDOWN invnext;bind MWHEELUP invprev;alias bhop bhopon; playvol buttons\blip2 0.25"
```

But, it does not work, here is output what im getting in console:

```
FCVAR_CLIENTCMD_CAN_EXECUTE prevented running command: bind
Tried to look up command bind as if it were a variable.
FCVAR_CLIENTCMD_CAN_EXECUTE prevented running command: bind
Tried to look up command bind as if it were a variable.
FCVAR_CLIENTCMD_CAN_EXECUTE prevented running command: alias
Tried to look up command alias as if it were a variable.
FCVAR_CLIENTCMD_CAN_EXECUTE prevented running command: playvol
Tried to look up command playvol as if it were a variable.
Unknown command: bind
Unknown command: bind
Unknown command: alias
Unknown command: playvol
```

Comment: The exact console output would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unverified guess, as I only know this error message from CS:S, where you weren't allowed to use commands like yours from the `teammenu.res`. This is similar to `radiopanel.txt` in Go.

If I am correct you cannot use commands like these in your `radiopanel.txt`. Instead you can bind the script to an unused key.

This works:

```
bind F6 "bhopon"
alias bhopon "bind MWHEELDOWN +jump;bind MWHEELUP +jump;bind F6 bhopoff; playvol buttons\blip1 0.25"
alias bhopoff "bind MWHEELDOWN invnext;bind MWHEELUP invprev;bind F6 bhopon; playvol buttons\blip2 0.25"
```

Comment: Ahh ok, so its not able to do?

Comment: Not from radiopanel at least. You can still bind it to a regular key.

Comment: Presumably it's to stop HUD makers from doing bad things like rebinding all your keys.